# Is it incorrect to use a comma as a pause in this sentence:

Tags: punctuation

"That, has been a long time coming!" A friend of mine insists that I should have used an ellipsis.

Comment: Your friend is correct.

Comment: If your goal is to emphatically assert the *that*, italics are your friend: "*That* has been a long time coming!"

Comment: Thank you, RegDwight.